# error with integer variable in glm.fit in r

Tags: r, regression

```
Result=glm(dep~re+ind1+ind2+ind3, data=ds,family=binomial)
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

re is an integer variable that takes a value from 0 to 6, and if I exclude this I don't get the error above anymore.
The following are the data types of the variable re fyi. Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
> typeof(ds$re)
[1] "integer"
> class(ds$re)
[1] "integer"
> is.numeric(ds$re)
[1] TRUE

> summary(ds$re)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   0.000   2.000   2.189   4.000   6.000
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that `re` is an integer. The message tells us that `re` causes complete separation of your data. In other words, `dep` is completely predictable from `re`, so some of the probabilities are 0 or 1.

Although we don't have your data, we can construct a dataset which produces the same error using exactly your code simply by making `dep` completely dependent on `re`:

```r
set.seed(1)
ds <- data.frame(re = as.integer(sample(0:6, 20, TRUE)),
                 ind1 = rnorm(20), ind2 = rnorm(20), ind3 = rnorm(20))
ds$dep <- ifelse(ds$re > 3, 1, 0)
```

If we run your code on this, we get:

```r
Result = glm(dep~re+ind1+ind2+ind3, data=ds,family=binomial)
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

If we look at the predicted probabilities, we will see that, within one part in a billion, the probabilities are either 0 or 1:

```r
round(predict(Result, type = "response"), 9)
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
#>  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1
```

The fix for this depends very much on context and your actual data, neither of which are included in the question. For example, with my made-up data set, we could just throw out the model and say that we can predict `dep` perfectly using `re` without the other variables. Your own data might have other problems.

<sup>Created on 2022-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>